# convert single digit to double digit values in python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nlp, digits

I am creating dictionary of characters in python. My total characters are close to 70. Problem is my first 10 characters has SINGLE DIGIT values, but I want all my characters to have DOUBLE DIGIT values. How can I achieve that?
Given:

```
char_vec = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m']
print(char_vec)
dict_temp = { i:ch for i,ch in enumerate(char_vec) }
dict_temp_rev = { i:ch for ch,i in enumerate(char_vec) }
print('given dict')
print(dict_temp)
print('reverse way')
print(dict_temp_rev)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
given dict
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j', 10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm'}
reverse way
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12}
```

What I expect (not as printed values in the terminal but inside the dictionary):

```
{00: 'a', 01: 'b', 02: 'c', 03: 'd', 04: 'e', 05: 'f', 06: 'g', 07: 'h', 08: 'i', 09: 'j', 10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm'}

{'a': 00, 'b': 01, 'c': 02, 'd': 03, 'e': 04, 'f': 05, 'g': 06, 'h': 07, 'i': 08, 'j': 09, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the way of achieving that for the actual values, not just printed output without converting your integer keys to strings:

```
dict_temp = {str(i).zfill(2) : ch for i, ch in enumerate(char_vec)}
print(dict_temp)
```

Output:

```
{'00': 'a', '01': 'b', '02': 'c', '03': 'd', '04': 'e', '05': 'f', '06': 'g', '07': 'h', '08': 'i', '09': 'j', '10': 'k', '11': 'l', '12': 'm'}
```

Comment: Thanx @Yelyzaveta Velizhanina! This won't solve my problem since I will need to employ these values for training my neural network. I have decided to start enumerating from 11 instead.